# Using authority-given .cer file to login on remote servers on OS X

Tags: security, ssh, mac-osx, ssh-keys

A few months ago I bought a certificate from a popular certification authority (Certum). I used it to sign emails, but today the admin at my work asked me to connect to our main server via ssh. He gave me a generated (by himself) .ppk file (which I've converted to .pem file), the .ppk's password and login details.

I wonder if there's any way that I can use my own bought .cer file to securely connect to server. Of course I understand that the server has to have my public key under .ssh and I need to use a private key to login. The real question is: is it even possible to split a .cer file to public and private keys compatible with both OS X and our server? 
The server runs on FreeBSD 8.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, but I would advise against it. If you use the same key for everything, and that key gets compromised, you will have to change it everywhere - much like if you're using the same password for different services. Don't do that.

That said, if you still want to do that, it's possible.

The .cer file contains both the public and the private key. SSH wants to have separate files for private and public keys, so the first thing you need to do is split it up. You'll ususally do this with openssl:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in yourcertfile.cer -noout -pubkey > identity.pub    
openssl rsa -inform der -in yourcertfile.cer -out identity
```